# Is there a name for a multiplicative function $\psi(p^n) = (p^n-1)(p^{n-1}-1)\cdots(p-1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

I have come across a multiplicative function (almost always named "$\psi$") defined on prime powers by
$$\psi(p^n) = (p^n - 1)(p^{n-1} - 1) \cdots (p-1),$$
for primes $p$ and integers $n\geq 0$. (So, $\psi(1)=1$ and $\psi(ab) = \psi(a)\psi(b)$, for relatively prime positive integers $a$ and $b$). However, no author I've read so far has stated a non-symbolic name for this, and I didn't get anything close to this using Google.

*Does this $\psi$ have a name?  Is it something well-studied in number theory?*

(Note that it coincides with Euler's $\phi$ on square-free positive integers.)

**Context.** This function arises in characterising orders of finite groups with certain properties.

Comment: $$(x^n - 1)(x^{n-1} - 1) \cdots (x-1) = \sum_{k=1}^n (x^k-1)=(-1)^m(x;x)_n$$
This is a particular case of q-Pochhammer special function.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html

In the particular case $x=p$ with prime $p$, as far as I know there is no particular name for this sub-case of Pochhammer series.

Comment: You saw that in Thomas Mueller's paper in the Journal of Algebra, right? :)

Comment: @the_fox I'm not at home with my material right now, but I believe that was one of them, yes.

Comment: @James: Could you cite a paper where this function is used?

Comment: @Markus Scheuer The [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82077614.pdf) by Thomas Mueller mentioned in an earlier comment is one example.

Comment: @James: Many thanks for the information.